# Changing node values in XML using VBS with similar names

Tags: vbscript

I am facing this challenge with changing values of nodes in an xml file which has same names, using VBScript. Following is the sample XML:

```html
- <MappingData>
   <Name>Name 1</Name> 
 - <ValueField FieldName="Name 2">
  <CharValue>Value 1</CharValue> 
  </ValueField>
 - <ValueField FieldName="Name 3">
  <CharValue>Value 1</CharValue> 
  </ValueField>
```

My requirement is to change the values of both occurrences of tag

```html
<CharValue>
```

.
I could have done this if there was any attribute in these tags, but in this case I am stuck.

I tried the following code, but could'nt get what I need.

```
Set NodeList = objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("//MappingData/ValueField/CharValue") 
For i = 0 To NodeList.length - 1
    node.Text = "Value 1"
Next
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Change the value in the xml object or in the xml file?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I want to change value in XML file for these tags. I am able to make changes in file for other tags, but this scenario I am unable to make changes with the code I have given.

Comment: `node.Text = "Value 1"` is incorrect because there is nothing called `node` in your code. It should be `NodeList`, which may be an array of node objects.

Comment: Absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
Set xDoc = CreateObject( "Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0" )
xDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xDoc.async = False
xDoc.load "test.xml"

Set nNodes = xDoc.selectNodes("//MappingData/ValueField/CharValue")
For i = 0 To nNodes.Length - 1
  nNodes(i).text = "Changed value " & i
Next

xDoc.Save "test.xml"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Pankaj, it worked :) documentElement was not necessary in Set Node of my code. Thanks again for quick resolution.

Comment: @J.A. - Happy to help. Don't forget to mark it as [**Accepted**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if this works for you.